# Typescript: Is it possible to evaluate generic type into string literal?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to evaluate generic type into a string literal without being explicit?

Here is an example what I have in mind:

```
function foo<T>(type: T): { type: T } {
    return { type };
}

// type is { type: string } I would like it to be { type: 'FooBar' } without being explicit
const bar = foo('FooBar'); 

// is it possible not to do this and get same result?
const fooBar = foo<'FooBar'>('FooBar'); 
const barFoo = foo('FooBar' as const);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfACigTwAcBTALkQwEpyBvRAk8jRAX0RoChFvEAnYqCF5I6DYqwDcHFhw4B6OfSLiYAZ3ZLGiVVF4wwAc1aIAkogDucEABsAJomswA1iqj04iAEbjRy8gHIAMVQAIQBDXn9jcxgoAAsrN299I2IAD0JHCFiOCAQdLwjEAF5kVBwg0Ij-SglEWQVENSa3QjhVVRhPa3EwODcoD1sPeOawsHsDAW0wgFtxflUbKAB+XPy3FDhw3hKy9Ert6txDnZq69bACzwjgj1KtiruzxDD1PKuoWqA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also bit surprised [Literal Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) doesnt propagate to `foo` function and instead it defaults to `string` type.

```js
const test = 'FooBar';
const barFoo = foo(test);
```

However, when I explicity specify type there is no problem.

```js
const test: 'FooBar' = 'FooBar';
const barFoo = foo(test);
```

Well this is where we started.

With a little bit of fiddling in `foo` function:

```js
function foo<T extends string>(type: T): { type: T } {
    return { type };
}

const test = 'FooBar';
const barFoo = foo(test);
```

I was looking at intellisense result when I peeked at expression and it now propagates the type.